How does a database recovery technique can be both no-steal and force at the same time?
No-steal means that the cache can't be flushed to the disk until the transaction commits.
Force means the the cache is immediately flushed to disk.
So, how a technique can be both No-steal and Force at the same time?
I want to understand the difference in these terms steal/no-steal and force/no-force associated with database recovery techniques and examples related to them.
I have found following from Chat-GPT but not sure that if it is correct or not.
"No-steal" implies that uncommitted changes cannot be written to disk, ensuring that only committed data is durably stored. On the other hand, "force" means that log records associated with committed transactions are immediately written to disk to ensure durability.
So, a technique can either be "no-steal" or "force," but not both at the same time.
